# Suppose $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and $f(x_0) = 1$. Show that there is $\rho$ with $\lvert f'(\rho) \rvert \geq 2$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose that $f : [0; 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continous and differentiable on $(0,1)$, that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, and that $\exists_{x_0 \in (0; 1)} f(x_0) = 1$.

Prove that $\exists_{\rho \in (0;1)}|f'(\rho)| > 2$. Any hints how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities.

If $x_0 \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$, then we see that the average slope on $[0, x_0]$ is at least $2$. An application of the Mean Value Theorem guarantees you a $\rho$.

If $x_0 \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1]$, then the average slope on $[x_0, 1]$ is at least $2$. Then the Mean Value Theorem guarantees you a $\rho$. $\diamondsuit$